# Why did this game end with a draw?

Tags: draw, birds-opening

[This game](https://www.365chess.com/view_game.php?g=354900&m=4) starts with

1. f4  e5
2. g4

IMO, black has a winning position here. How did it end with a draw?

[image]

Comment: Blind guess: This was an arranged draw.

Comment: @Annatar, for an arranged draw, why not play some better moves than these?

Comment: @Zuriel: they are under 16 and playing a game. Why not play the worst moves possible?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, if this is an extremely short arranged draw with terrible moves, is it against FIDE tournament rules that "8.(f) Where it is clear games have been pre-arranged, the CA shall impose suitable penalties." I am wondering what the organisers think about this draw game.

Comment: @Zuriel Did that rule exist in 2001?

Comment: @Annatar, good point! So there is nothing the arbiters could do about this game, except to acknowledge it as a draw?

Comment: @Zuriel: It was apparently recorded as a draw, so that's what happened. In practice if the game is meaningless (e.g. last round for players without sight of the prizes) nobody will care.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, even if it is not against any rules, I will still considered such games as improper and against the spirit of chess.

Comment: You can think what you want, so what's the point of this question?

Comment: @fkraiem, I was asking the reason(s) for the result since I thought it would be a win for black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either the game score is incorrectly recorded or this was a pre-arranged draw, because in that final position everyone beyond basic club level would realize that Black wins with Qh4# (a basic Fool's mate pattern).